# Scala Actors + Console.withOut possible bug

Tags: scala, actor, io-redirection

I found some strange behavior when `Console.withOut` used within an actor. For code:

```
case object I
val out = new PipedOutputStream
val pipe = new PipedInputStream(out)
def read: String = ** read from `pipe` stream
class A extends Actor{
  var b: Actor = _
  Console.withOut(out){
    b = actor { loop { self react {
          case I => println("II")
        }}}
    }
  def act = {
    loop { self react {
        case I =>
          println("I")
          b ! I
      }}
    }
  }
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val a = new A
  a.start
  a ! I
  Thread sleep 100
  println("!!\n" + read + "!!")
  }
```

got following output:

```
!!
I
II
!!
```

Any idea why output from `A` actor's `act` method is also redirected? Thank you for your answers.

**UPDATE:**
Here is read function:

```
  @tailrec
  def read(instream: InputStream, acc: List[Char] = Nil): String =
    if(instream.available > 0) read(instream, acc :+ instream.read.toChar) else acc mkString ""
  def read: String = read(pipe)
```

Comment: Could you also post the code with which you read from the `pipe`?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me, on the contrary, that neither actor has its output redirected, since `withOut` will have finished executing long before `println("II")` is called. Since this is all based on `DynamicVariable`, however, I'm not willing to bet on it. :-) The absence of working code precludes any testing as well.

Comment: Agreed. Neither should be visible. My thinking is that the code for the `read` does something it's not supposed to, hence the printing.

Comment: Agreed.  `withOut` is only active while `b` is _created_, not while it is responding to its message.  Consistent with this, the !!'s appear there also (presumably unredirected).  So either `read` calls `setOut` or nothing is redirected.

Comment: `read` doesn't call `setOut`, but all outputs after outer actor is started is redirected for a reason i cannot see.